# Use PHP regex to search and create an array from an XML document only containing top level tags with existing order

Tags: php, html, xml

[image: a simple office document with containing 2 pharagraphs and a table between them]

I have a PHP variable with a text string of XML. I need to pass its top level tags e.g. <w:p> and <w:tbl> (pharagraphs and tables in existing order) into an array like this without their contents.

A sample array with expected result.

- 'a pharagraph'
- 'a table'
- 'a pharagraph'

A sample PHP code so far I have done

```
<?php
 $text= <<<EOT
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
  <w:body>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00FC1847" w:rsidRDefault="00A526BC">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>foo</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR="007C7582">
        <w:t>0</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
    </w:p>
    <w:tbl>
      <w:tblPr>
        <w:tblStyle w:val="TabloKlavuzu"/>
        <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
        <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
      </w:tblPr>
      <w:tblGrid>
        <w:gridCol w:w="11329"/>
      </w:tblGrid>
      <w:tr w:rsidR="00A526BC" w:rsidTr="00A526BC">
        <w:tc>
          <w:tcPr>
            <w:tcW w:w="11329" w:type="dxa"/>
          </w:tcPr>
          <w:p w:rsidR="00A526BC" w:rsidRDefault="00A526BC">
            <w:r>
              <w:t>bar</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>
      </w:tr>
    </w:tbl>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00A526BC" w:rsidRDefault="00A526BC">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>baz</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00A526BC" w:rsidSect="00A526BC">
      <w:pgSz w:w="11907" w:h="16839" w:code="9"/>
      <w:pgMar w:top="459" w:right="284" w:bottom="1418" w:left="284" w:header="709" w:footer="709" w:gutter="0"/>
      <w:cols w:space="708"/>
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
EOT;
preg_match_all('%<w:p .*?>(.*?<w:r>.*?</w:r>).*?</w:p>%si', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

which results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => <w:r><w:t>foo</w:t></w:r>
    [1] => <w:r><w:t>bar</w:t></w:r>
    [2] => <w:r><w:t>baz</w:t></w:r>
)
```

Comment: Avoid solving this with a regular expression, it's far too complicated and dangerous. Typically, in your example, if you try matching `/<w:(p|tbl)\b.*?>/si` you'll get the paragraph which is inside the table and not only the top level items. You could try solving this with the formatting (matching new lines and spaces) but this will never work as the document will certainly not be formatted properly. Use an [XML parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) instead, it's made for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a regex, you can use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to get all the child elements using an xpath expression `/w:document/w:body/*`  and then check for example the nodeName:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($text);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$elms = [];
foreach ($xpath->query('/w:document/w:body/*') as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeName === "w:p") {
        $elms[] = "a paragraph";
    }
    if ($node->nodeName === "w:tbl") {
        $elms[] = "a table";
    }    
}

print_r($elms);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => a paragraph
    [1] => a table
    [2] => a paragraph
)
```

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Z8r2n).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use RegEx to parse XML, use an XML parser. Xpath expression allow you to fetch specific nodes.

Be aware that namespace prefixes/aliases are only valid for an element and its descendants until redefined. They can change between documents and even on a descendant node in the same document. The namespace URI is the unique identifier of an namespace. The prefix/alias is just for human readability/document size. I will use a prefix different from the one in the document in the example.

So you are looking for the child elements inside the `{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}body` element node ([Clark notation](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm)).

Load the data into an DOM document, register a prefix for the namespace and fetch the elements using an Xpath expression.

```php
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXMLString());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// register the namespace using your own prefix
$xpath->registerNamespace('main', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main');

$result = [];
// fetch children of the body element
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//main:body/*') as $mainElement) {
    // store namespace and node name
    $result[] = [
        'uri' => $mainElement->namespaceURI,
        'name' => $mainElement->localName
    ];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["uri"]=>
    string(60) "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "p"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["uri"]=>
    string(60) "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "tbl"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["uri"]=>
    string(60) "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "p"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["uri"]=>
    string(60) "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "sectPr"
  }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your showing me correct way of iterating through an XML document object. I was strugling with php array and regexes which I am not comfortable with. Now I am easily rewriting my code again. Really thanks.